# php validate integer

Tags: php

I`m wonder why this not working

```
    echo gettype($_GET['id']); //returns string
  if(is_int($_GET['id']))
  {
   echo 'Integer';
  }
```

How to validate data passing from GET/POST if it is integer ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The [**manual**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php) says:

> To test if a variable is a number or a
>   numeric string (such as form input,
>   which is always a string), you must
>   use is_numeric().

Alternative you can use the regex based test as:

```
if(preg_match('/^\d+$/',$_GET['id'])) {
  // valid input.
} else {
  // invalid input.
}
```

Comment: ...and also accepts decimal numbers.  `preg_match` FTW.  It can also accept inputs like `04`.

Comment: Shouldn't the preg_match accept negative numbers too? As far as I know, an Integer can be negative, so -5 should be accepted as Int.

Comment: I also want to set the length in preg_match then how to do that ??

Answer (score 33):

Can use

```
$validatedValue = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
```

See http://php.net/filter_input and related functions.

Answer (score 3):

What about [`intval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)?

```
$int = intval($_GET['id']);
```

Comment: Great solution, but inval(0) returns 0, then in your test 0 will not be considireted as a INTEGER

$value =0;
if(!intval($value)) {
 throw new Exception(...); // Throw a exception for zero
}

Answer (score 3):

To validate form data (string) as an integer, you should use `ctype_digit()`
It returns `TRUE` if every character in the string text is a decimal digit, `FALSE` otherwise.
(PHP 4 >= 4.0.4, PHP 5)

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php

Comment: `ctype_digit()` will only check a string, so `ctype_digit(1) === false`, while `ctype_digit('1') === true`. This is very useful for validating user input, as $_GET and $_POST contain strings.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if(isNumeric($_GET['id'])) {
    $cast_int = (int)$_GET['id'];
}

if(isset($cast_int)) {
    echo gettype($cast_int)."<br />\n";
    if(is_int($cast_int))
    {
        echo 'Integer'."<br />\n";
    }
} else {
    echo gettype($_GET['id'])." was passed<br />\n";
}

function isNumeric($numeric) {
    return preg_match("/^[0-9]+$/", $numeric);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are checking if a string contains an integer, rather than if that variable **is** an integer.  If so, you should check out php's regex (regular expression) functionality.  It allows you to check for very specific patterns in a string to validate it for whatever criteria. (such as if it contains only number characters)

Here's the php page 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

and here's a cheat sheet on regular expressions (to make the $pattern string)
http://regexpr.com/cheatsheet/

Answer (score -1):

I take a slightly more paranoid approach to sanitizing GET input

```
function sanitize_int($integer, $min='', $max='')
{
  $int = intval($integer);
  if((($min != '') && ($int < $min)) || (($max != '') && ($int > $max)))
    return FALSE;
  return $int;
}
```

To be even safer, you can extract only numbers first and then run the function above

```
function sanitize_paranoid_string($string, $min='', $max='')
{
  $string = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $string);
  $len = strlen($string);
  if((($min != '') && ($len < $min)) || (($max != '') && ($len > $max)))
    return FALSE;
  return $string;
}
```

Code from: http://libox.net