# php: Best way to validate integers and filter out invalid chars

Tags: php, security, validation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php validate integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100022/php-validate-integer)

Currently I'm using this method:

1. Validate the input using `isset($val) && is_numeric($val)`
2. Cast it to `int` and passing it to the function: `DoSomething((int)$val);`

So my question is this: Is this the fastest and most practical way to do this? If I cast the value to `int`, is the `int` range enough for the maximum number of rows in the `mysql` database?

Comment: `filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)`

Comment: And please ask only one question at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems the method is quite redundant.

either validate or cast - no need to do both.

And this is apparently not a place that needs to be "fastest".

Answer (score 3):

PHP offers integrated [basic filter & validation functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php).

Answer (score 1):

a quick look at php manual page shoved that:

```
$foo = 5a;
settype($foo, "integer"); // $foo is now 5   (integer)
```

And:
/* checks if a string is an integer with possible whitespace before and/or after, and also isolates the integer */

```
$isInt=preg_match('/^\s*([0-9]+)\s*$/', $myString, $myInt);
```