# php 5.4 magic_quotes_gpc alternative?

Tags: php

I was using `php 5.2` earlier. Now I want to upgrade `php 5.4.` Magic quotes are removed now. I want to make my application work properly. Which function I should use for escaping data `mysql_real_escape_string()` or `addslashes()` ?

Which function from the above will give the same results as of `magic_quotes_gpc` setting??

Comment: It depends on the database layer your application is using. There is *one* proper escaping function for each database library.

Comment: Does your application rely on `magic_quotes_gpc`? which is a very bad idea.

Comment: Yes xdazz. It is. It is very old application and I have to make it work.

Comment: @Pekka, I am not using any database layer as it is very old application and I am using mysql functions.

Comment: @TanuGupta: So your database layer is [`mysql_*`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) then

Comment: @Eric: Yes, we are using mysql_* functions for mysql interaction.

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string()` is better than `addslashes()`, which filters more illegal characters. If you are handling legacy code, you can use [php-magic-quotes](https://github.com/yidas/php-magic-quotes) to implement `magic_quotes_gpc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its better to use prepared statements as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2353687/1965084) for security reasons. Mysql_real_escape_string might not be suffiecient to prevent sql injection e.g. because multibyte character sets can be abused despite the escape function ().[mysql_real_escape_string() versus Prepared Statements](http://ilia.ws/archives/103-mysql_real_escape_string-versus-Prepared-Statements.html).

Prepared statements in PHP can be used like this:

```
  $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (?, ?)");
  $stmt->bindParam(1, $name);
  $stmt->bindParam(2, $value);
```

[More information on prepared statements in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). So in conclusion, if you have the possibility to change your application to prepared statements, that would be the best way to handle.

**UPDATE (totally not recommended)**

If you really want to keep the state, use addslashes() for every $GET and $POST variable. It does the same manually what magic_quotes switched on did with all $GET and $POST variables. But i really guess its less work to use mysqli with mysqli_real_escape_string or better, prepared statements :)

http://php.net/manual/de/function.addslashes.php

Comment: It is old application alex. and I am not using PDO in this application. I just have to make it work until I upgrade to some db layer.

Comment: The is it possible for you to use mysqli http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php ? It keeps the charset issue in mind.

Comment: Thanks alex. Cant modify the code at this level as its a big application. just need a quick solution which can give me the same output what magic_quotes_gpc setting gives.

Answer (score 2):

It's always best to migrate to PDO and prepared statements as outlined by @alex above.

If that isn't feasible, absolutely escape incoming string data with `mysql_real_escape_string()`, and validate integer data, e.g. using `filter_input()` as shown in [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9080284/187606)

`addslashes()`  is not a suitable escaping method for mySQL queries.

Comment: I just want a function which can give me the same results as I get when magic_quotes_gpc setting is on. I can not modify my db layer. I just want a quick solution which just serves the purpose and helps me making my application work properly. I think addslashes() is solving the purpose because it escapes single quote ('), double quote ("), backslash (\) and NUL (the NULL byte) just like magic quotes do.

Comment: `addslashes()` is not enough to secure incoming data; it is not a 100% perfect protection. `mysql_real_escape_string()` is the way to go. It's just a different choice of functions, isn't it?

Comment: Actually I just need an alternative which is closer to magic_quotes_gpc. mysql_real_escape_string() escapes \x00, \n, \r, \, ', " and \x1a. I would need to make my application tested thoroughly if I use mysql_real_escape_string() and its a big application and I want to reduce my testing effort. Suggestions??

Comment: @Tanu those characters will be escaped only for the duration of the query; the slashes will not be in the final data. I don't see how this would need extensive testing.

Comment: As I said its very old application, I have some scripts where I get the data from db and remove escape character using some custom/ pre-defined functions.

Answer (score 1):

Because I can not introduce db layer on my application and I want a quick solution, I used addslashes() function because addslashes() escapes single quote ('), double quote ("), backslash () and NUL (the NULL byte) exactly what magic quotes escape.

Code:

```
    foreach (array('_COOKIE','_GET', '_POST') as $_SG) {
            foreach ($$_SG as $_SGK => $_SGV) {
                    $$_SGK = smartQuotes($_SGV);
            }
    }


    function smartQuotes($value)
    {
            if( is_array($value) ) {
                    return array_map("smartQuotes", $value);
            } else {
                    if( $value == '' ) {
                            $value = 'NULL';
                    } if( !is_numeric($value)) {
                            $value = addslashes($value);
                    }
                    return $value;
            }
    }
```

Comment: This will leave your application vulnerable under certain circumstances: [Examples of SQL Injections through addslashes()?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/860954)

Comment: True. Until I upgrade to PDO, its a quick fix for me.

Comment: `$$_SGK = smartQuotes($_SGV);` not only adds slashes, but also assigns the value to a global variable instead of $_GET,$_POST etc, ... like 'register_globals' used to do 10 years ago. Use `${$_SG}[$_SGK] = smartQuotes($_SGV);` instead to change the gpc globals.

Comment: .. dont forget  $_REQUEST (if you would change values in place)

Answer (score 0):

`addslashes()` gives the same results as of `magic_quotes_gpc` setting referring from [Magic Quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.what.php).

> When on, all ' (single-quote), " (double quote), \ (backslash) and NULL characters are escaped with a backslash automatically. This is identical to what [addslashes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) does.

---

#### Use magic_quotes_gpc on PHP 5.4 above

If you still want run `magic_quotes_gpc` on PHP 5.4 or higher version for your legacy code, you can use [yidas/magic-quotes](https://github.com/yidas/php-magic-quotes):

> https://github.com/yidas/php-magic-quotes

Answer (score 0):

We need to addslashes in Request, Post, Get & cookie. You can achieve it below code.  Included below code in your common file .

```
$la_magicQuotes = array('_REQUEST','_POST', '_GET','_COOKIE');
  foreach($la_magicQuotes as $la_superGlobal )
  { 
    if($$la_superGlobal && is_array($$la_superGlobal))    
      array_walk($$la_superGlobal, 'pr_addslashed_array');
  }


function pr_addslashed_array(&$la_val,$lc_key) 
{  
  if (is_array($la_val))
    array_walk($la_val,'pr_addslashed_array');
  else
    $la_val = pr_addslashed($la_val);   
}

function pr_addslashed($lc_string)
{
  return $lc_string = addslashes($lc_string);   
}
```